# htaccess redirects only with hard refresh

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site in React.js on http://example.com, which uses wordpress API, which is located in example/wp subfolder.
I have one htaccess in root folder:

```
# BEGIN redirection to https
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   </IfModule>
# END redirection to https

# BEGIN needed for client side routing
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
      RewriteRule ^.*$ / [L,QSA]
   </IfModule>
# END needed for client side routing
```

and in example/wp another htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wp/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The problem appeared after switching to https. When accessing example/wp/wp-admin I get notFound page from react app instead of wordpress admin panel. But when I hard refresh the page, I get redirected to the admin panel.
Why?
When I add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*/testingurl
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://someOtherexample.com [R=301,L]
```

I also get example/testingurl, but after hard refreshing I get redirected to someOtherexample.com.
What I am missing?

Comment: Explain “accessing”. Do you mean that you click on a link from within your react app, or that you directly enter the URL via the browser address bar? In the first case, most likely your client-side react routing is taking over, and then says 404 because it doesn’t find any specific content for that route. When you refresh now, that request is send to the server (which it wasn’t before, because of react’s _client-side_ routing), which will realize that `/wp` matches a physically existing directory, so it goes into that, and then the WP routing can apply.